# Image Preview from DB

Tags: php, laravel, migration, relation

I'm Trying to Preview images from database as im saving album in table albums and album images in table images and connecting with relation but i can't preview the images from table image so i'm adding relations between the 2 tables and trying to preview the images but its not working with me something went wrong but i cannot figure it

Blade.php

```
<tbody>
@foreach ($albums as $album)

<tr>
    <th scope="row">{{$album->id}}</th>
    <td>{{$album->name}}</td>
    <td>{{$album->category_id}}</td>
    <td><img style="width:5vw; hieght:5vh" src="{{$album->id}}" alt=""></td>
    <td>
        <a href="{{route('albums.show',$album->id)}}" class="btn btn-success">Show</a>
        @if (Auth::user()->role_id==1)
        <a href="{{route('albums.edit',$album->id)}}" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</a>
        <form action="{{route('albums.destroy',$album->id)}}" method="post" class="d-inline">
        @csrf
        @method('DELETE')
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete" />
        </form>
@else
@endif

    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
```

AlbumsController

```
    public function index()
    {
        $albums = Album::with('images')->get();
                return view('admin.albums.all',compact('albums'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $albums=Album::all();
        $categories=Category::all();
        return view('admin.albums.create',compact('categories'));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $album=Album::create([
            'name'=>$request->name,
            'price'=>$request->price,
            'image'=>$request->image,
            'category_id'=>$request->category_id,
        ]);
        foreach($request->images as $image){
            $filename = $image->store('album');
            $images=Image::create([
                'album_id' => $album->id,
                'filename' => $filename
            ]);
        }
        $albums=Album::with('images')->get();
        return view('admin.albums.all',compact('albums'));
    }
```

Image Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Image extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = ['album_id','filename'];

    public function images(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Album::class,'id');
    }
}
```

Album Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Album extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'category_id',
    ];
    public function categories(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class,'category_id','id');
    }
    public function images(){
        return $this->HasMany(Image::class,'filename','id');
    }
}
```

table images Migration

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->biginteger('album_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('album_id')->references('id')->on('albums');
            $table->string('filename');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('images');
    }
};
```

Table albums Migration

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('albums', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->integer('category_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('albums');
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<img style="width:5vw; hieght:5vh" src="{{$album->id}}" alt="">`

1. Do you have image with that id with no file extension at the end like {{ $album->id}}.png ?
2. Your `Album` model looks wrong

```php
<?php
class Album extends Model
{
    public function images(){
        // Laravel can figure it out if you use the convention
        return $this->hasMany(Image::class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have an invalid foreign key in your model Album. In yours code 'filename'

```
images(){
        return $this->HasMany(Image::class,'filename','id');
    }
```

However in migration for image table you set another foreign key
`$table->foreign('album_id')->references('id')->on('albums');`